# Get list of values of matrix from indices list in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indices

I have a matrix like this:

```
A = [35,  1,   6,  26;
     3,   32,  7,  21;
     31   9,   2,  22;
     8,   28,  3,  17];
```

and a list of indices like this:

```
B = [1,  1;
     1,  2;
     2,  2;
     1,  3];
```

I want to get list of values from matrix A with indices in B

```
C = [35, 1, 32, 6]
```

I use this code:

```
C = A(B==1)
```

But the C is :

```
[35, 3, 8, 1]
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sub2ind`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert your `row,col` indexing to linear indexing.

```
A = [35,  1,   6,  26;
     3,   32,  7,  21;
     31   9,   2,  22;
     8,   28,  3,  17];

B = [1,  1;
     1,  2;
     2,  2;
     1,  3];

linear_ind = sub2ind(size(A), B(:,1), B(:,2));
C = A(linear_ind)
```

Which will result in

```
C =
    35
     1
    32
     6
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if A and B is 3D?

Comment: @MortezaTest you can still use `sub2ind`, multidimensional subscripts are supported, see the [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html#mw_fa3c7b6d-8fe6-496b-a134-9bea1611682d).